# Calling intent in the list view

Tags: android, listview, android-intent

I am developing android application. I am using the web service to retrive the data in my application. Now in one of my function i fetch the employee's full detail and display it in the list view. Now in list view there are certain phone numbers (More then 2)are their. Now i want to use call intent is it possible in the list view if yes let me know the way.Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
onlistitemclick you enter below code as per position.............  



                    AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                            Contact.this);
                    alertbox.setTitle("Calling...");
                    alertbox.setMessage("773-288-1456");

                    alertbox.setPositiveButton("Call",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                // do something when the button is clicked
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                                    Intent callIntent = new Intent(
                                            Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                                    callIntent.setData(Uri
                                            .parse("tel:773-288-1456"));
                                    startActivity(callIntent);
                                }
                            });

                    // set a negative/no button and create a listener
                    alertbox.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                                }
                            });

                    // display box
                    alertbox.show();
```

Comment: but i have multiple numbers in the list view. One employee have multiple numbers.

Comment: i have used 4 rows out of which in 3 rows the numbers are display.

Comment: You got position in listview first row position is zero using switch sttement you can get each row value.......

Answer (score 0):

use

> onItemClickListener

of the listView and call the intent you want in the

> onClick

method of it.